# Why does the terminal returns `Cannot send an empty message` when I run the command?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to do a pokemon command but for some reason, it is returning as `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Cannot send an empty message`. Here is the code and I am hoping that this platform will help me resolve my issue.

```
const rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 802);
const poke = rand > 0 ? rand : Math.floor(Math.random() * 802);
const pokem = pokemon[poke];

const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
  .setTitle("️ Time is ticking! You have 15 seconds to answer | WHO'S THAT POKEMON?!")
  .setColor(colored[~~(Math.random() * colored.length)])
  .setAuthor(message.member.displayName, message.author.displayAvatarURL())
  .setImage(pokem.imageURL);

const msg = await message.channel.send(embed);
const filter = m => m.author.id === message.author.id;
const attempts = await msg.channel.awaitMessages(filter, { time: 15000, max: 1 });

if (!attempts || !attempts.size) {
  msg.delete();
  const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle("️ Time is up!")
    .setColor(colored[~~(Math.random() * colored.length)])
    .setDescription(`Ba-Baka! Your 15 seconds is over. It was \`${pokem.name}\`.`);

  return message.channel.send(embed);
}

const answer = attempts.first().content.toLowerCase();

if (answer === pokem.name.toLowerCase()) {
  await msg.edit({ embed: null });
  let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle("<a:done:707045670661652481> Correct")
    .setColor(colored[~~(Math.random() * colored.length)])
    .setDescription(`Yatta! Well done, \`${pokem.name}\` was correct.`);

  return message.channel.send(embed);
}
await msg.edit({ embed: null });
embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
  .setTitle("<a:error:707045703003668521> Incorrect")
  .setColor(colored[~~(Math.random() * colored.length)])
  .setDescription(`Ba-Baka! You answered incorrectly, It was \`${pokem.name}\`.**`);

return message.channel.send(embed);
```

Comment: Provide more detail about your error what has been throw on your terminal.

Comment: Please accept the answer below if it solved your question to let others know it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are editing the message with `{embed: null}`. As the message only has an embed, this removes the embed and there is therefore no content to edit the message with.

If I interpreted the code correctly, you want to update the embed, so use this:

```js
// Using let here so that embed can be reassigned later
let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
     .setTitle("️ Time is ticking! You have 15 seconds to answer | WHO'S THAT POKEMON?!")
     .setColor(colored[~~(Math.random() * colored.length)])
     .setAuthor(message.member.displayName, message.author.displayAvatarURL())
     .setImage(pokem.imageURL)

// rest of code...

if (answer === pokem.name.toLowerCase()) {
 let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle("<a:done:707045670661652481> Correct")
    .setColor(colored[~~(Math.random() * colored.length)])
    .setDescription(`Yatta! Well done, \`${pokem.name}\` was correct.`);
  // {embed} is shorthand for {embed: embed}
  await msg.edit({embed});
  return message.channel.send(embed);
}
// Instead of reassigning to embed, you could also create a new variable
embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle("<a:error:707045703003668521> Incorrect")
    .setColor(colored[~~(Math.random() * colored.length)])
    .setDescription(`Ba-Baka! You answered incorrectly, It was \`${pokem.name}\`.**`);
await msg.edit({embed});
```